# Calling JSON API from node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, request, httprequest

I am trying to call an API within my node.js application. The API returns JSON formatted data.

I have tried the "http" as well as the "request" module. I am perfectly able to make the request and receive data. But unfortunately the JSON response contains escape characters.

Like this i.e.:

> "/*-secure-\n{\"payload\":{\"id\":\"some-id\",\"path\":\"some-path\",....

This does not only look bad, but it also can't be processed as JSON.

When I call the api with my browser or via a REST client like postman, the response data looks just fine:

> /*-secure-{"payload":{"id":"some-id","dirname":"some-path",...

So is there any way to receive the data without those escape characters? Or do I have to remove them manually via string manipulation?

My example request looks like this:

```
var request = require('request');

var options = {
    url: 'http://url.tld/api/request.json?resource=example',
    json: true
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        res.json(body);
    }
}

request(options, callback);
```

I hope you guys can help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's not JSON... it's JSON in a string wrapped in a comment to prevent execution.  Are you sure the URLs you're calling in a browser and with your Node.js app are the same?  What about the headers?  There is probably a way to make a request that doesn't add the padding.